# Am I using mockito wrong?

Tags: junit, mockito

I wrote this test:

```
@Test
public void testDistance() {
    World world = mock(World.class);

    AbstractWarp warp = mock(AbstractWarp.class);
    Location loc = new Location(world, 0, 0, 0);
    when(warp.getLocation()).thenReturn(loc);

    Player player = mock(Player.class);
    Location loc2 = new Location(world, 100, 0, 0);
    when(player.getLocation()).thenReturn(loc2);

    double expected = 100;
    double actual = warp.distance(player);

    verify(player).getLocation();
    verify(warp).getLocation();
    assertEquals(expected, loc.distance(loc2), .1);
    assertEquals(expected, actual, .1);
}
```

for this method in the AbstractWarp class:

```
public double distance(Player player) {
    return player.getLocation().distance(getLocation());
}
```

And I can't figure out why the first verification fails with the following trace:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
player.getLocation();
-> at paperwarp.domain.AbstractWarpTest.testDistance(AbstractWarpTest.java:36)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you have created a mock for AbstractWarp and therefore your actual implementation of `AbstractWarp.distance` is never being called.

What you need for `AbstractWarp` is a `spy` instead of a `mock` like this:

```
AbstractWarp warp = spy(new AbstractWarp()); //instead of new AbstractWarp() use whatever other initialization is appropriate
doReturn(loc).when(warp).getLocation();
```

Note that if you aren't actually going to be calling `AbstractWarp.getLocation`, you don't need the `spy` at all for `AbstractWarp`. A regular class will do just fine

Comment: I'd say that he's actually mocking the `class under test`, so there's not much "real testing" going on

Comment: Thankyou. But AbstractWarp is an abstract class, I can't create an instance of it. Should I use an anonymous class extending from it?

Comment: @Aeron That would be the easiest thing to do

Comment: My tests usually follow the same implementation pattern, that is abstract test with common methods, and custom implementation with according methods